# Setting a value to a combobox - EXTJS - BEGINNER

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch

I am trying to set a value to a combobox, and the code is as follows:

The problem i am getting it is that the value isn't getting set.

```
var t= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#WindowID> #formId> #comboID')[0];
t.setValue('SOME v');
```

I also tried `setText`, there was no use.

Comment: Can you post the code of combobox you are trying to modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the value directly, try using

```
combo.setRawValue('SOME VALUE')
```

but be aware that this bypasses value conversion, change detection, and validation.

Visit http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setRawValue